# Display php Variable on Smarty Template 3

Tags: php, templates, smarty, smarty3

I've been trying to display a php variable on a smarty template, but it have been impossible.

**On my tpl i have:**

```
<a href="#">Welcome <strong><!--{$username}--></strong></a>
```

**On my php i have:**

```
<?php
require('../common/Smarty/config.php');             //Smarty Config Class
require_once('../common/config/config.php');        //Project Config Class  
require_once('../common/classes/Login.php');        //Login Class 

$smarty = new Smarty();

$template = "login.tpl";

$smarty->assign ( "username", $user_name );         //first: smarty variable, last: php variable.
$smarty->display ( "{$template}" );
?>
```

What im trying to do is too display the username of the user at login page.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW i use <!--{ and }--> as Smarty Delimiters

Comment: At `$smarty->display ( "{$template}" );`, smarty expects the template file name or another valid template resource. I think its not that optimal to abuse html comments as smarty delimters. Imagine you want to actually use html comments in your code, you will probably get a smarty syntax error then

Comment: The template is displaying properly, evrything fine with images and css, the problem is trying to show the $user_name variable. In fact, if i delete: $user_name, and i add something like "Peter", the template display that name.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What do you get instead of the translated value?

Comment: i got nothing, but if i add: $smarty->assign ( "username", Peter); for instace, i got: Welcome Peter!. looks like is not taking the username from the DB (but it is working the login). The $user_name variable is on the Login.php class

Comment: Mmmh, have you ensured that the encoding is properly set?

Comment: I would recommend you to set `$smarty->debugging = true` for test purpose. see here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.debugging.tpl

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your Smarty lib tpl you should just write {$username} where you want the user name to appear in the login.tpl file.

change this

```
<a href="#">Welcome <strong><!--{$username}-->``</strong></a>
```

to this

```
<a href="#">Welcome <strong>{$username}</strong></a>
```

The above works for me

Comment: Not working, i got: Welcome {$username}.     (im no using {} as delimters, im using <!--{ but that is no the problem. As i said before, if i change $user_name to a name for instance, it is displayed.

Comment: DEBUG the following:

echo out $user_name in your php file before it gets to the smarty var declaration. What do you get?

Comment: Hello, sorry for very late answer i had to travel for a personal emergency. Anyway, the code above is working. Thanks for your help. i really appreciate it.